# Wordpress - Approve modified posts

Tags: wordpress, edit, posts

I simply want to be able to re-approve my contributor's edits to an already published post.
so when they edit a post it gets sent back for approval.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: It will probably help on maiorano's goodwill if you edit your question to say "How" instead of "is". I also think it would be delightful if you could share with us how this can be done, maiorano84.

Comment: Maybe you're searching for something like the [approval workflow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/approval-workflow/)-plugin (there are [other plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/workflow) which do similar things).